# Recursive function that return result from 'if' statement instead of 'else' statement

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I'm pretty new in Python and I'm trying to write a simple recursive function:

```
def bugged_recursion(inp_value,list_index=0):
    '''Define a recursive function that tag lists according to one parameter.
    '''
    #check if a criterion is true at position 0 in the list
    if list_index == 0:
        if inp_value[list_index] == 'valid':
            status = 'valid inp_value'
        #if the criterion is false call the function at the next index
        else:
            status = 'invalid inp'
            list_index +=1
            bugged_recursion(inp_value,list_index=list_index)
    #check if a criterion is true at position 1 in the list
    else:
        if inp_value[list_index] == 'valid':
            status = 'index {} is a valid inp_value'.format(list_index)
        else:
            status = 'index is never a valid inp_value'
    print(status)
    #return the input and its status
    return (inp_value,status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inp_value = ['invalid','invalid']
    bugged_recursion(inp_value)
```

I don't understand why this function return the status from the if statement, instead of returning the status contained in the last else statement.
For me, the strangest is that it prints the right status at some point but won't return it.

I'm unable to understand why... I'm really curious about how I could perform this task using a recursive function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow wow, how tortured this is.

```
def bugged_recursion(inp_value, list_index=0):
    # i don't get why you compare list_index here
    if list_index == 0:
        # you'll get an IndexError if list_index > len(inp_value)
        if inp_value[list_index] == 'valid':
            status = 'valid inp_value'
        else:
            status = 'invalid inp'
            # there is only one place where you increment list_index
            # i suppose there is something wrong here
            list_index +=1
            # you forgot to return here
            return bugged_recursion(inp_value, list_index=list_index)
    else:
        if inp_value[list_index] == 'valid':
            status = 'index {} is a valid inp_value'.format(list_index)
        else:
            status = 'index is never a valid inp_value'
    return (inp_value,status)
```

That aside, people usually tend to avoid [recursion](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Recursion/recursionsimple.html) as much as possible (for example on [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/dynamic_functions/stage6.html)).

Does this cover your needs?

```
def no_recursion(inp_value):
    for i, val in enumerate(inp_value):
        # you probably have a good reason to test the index
        if i == 0:
            if val == 'valid':
                yield 'valid inp_value: %s' % val
            else:
                yield 'invalid inp: %s' % val
        else:
            yield 'index %s is %s valid inp_value' % (
                i,
                'a' if val == 'valid' else 'never'
            )

print tuple(no_recursion(inp_value))
```

Gives: `('invalid inp: invalid', 'index 1 is never valid inp_value')`

Comment: Thanks for explaining both how to correct my code and how to write a better, non-recursive function. I didn't know that it was necessary to return bugged_recursion()

Apologies if I seem naive but I'm a self-learner, I'll have a look at both your link! Thanks for your help, I'm happy that I learned something today!